# Orcale 11g client installs error on 64 bit win server 2008 OS

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g

Checking operating system requirements ...
Expected result: One of 5.0,5.1,5.2,6.0
Actual Result: 6.1
Check complete. The overall result of this check is: Failed <<<<
Problem: Oracle Database 11g is not certified on the current operating system.

## Recommendation: Make sure you are installing the software on the correct platform.

Checking service pack requirements ...
Check complete. The overall result of this check is: Not executed <<<<
OUI-18001: The operating system 'Windows Vista Version 6.1' is not supported.

## Recommendation: Install the recommended Service Pack.

Checking physical memory requirements ...
Expected result: 128MB
Actual Result: 1023MB

## Check complete. The overall result of this check is: Passed

Checking the length of PATH environment variable...

## Check complete. The overall result of this check is: Passed

Checking Oracle Home path for spaces...

## Check complete. The overall result of this check is: Passed

Checking for Oracle Home incompatibilities ....
Actual Result: NEW_HOME

## Check complete. The overall result of this check is: Passed

Comment: Hi,  any one please help on this..

Comment: What version of 11g are use using?  11.1 or 11.2?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like your media isn't for Win2k8 R2.  V6.1 has been detected (Windows7/2008 R2), whereas its expecting 5.0, 5.1, 5.2 or 6.0 (Windows 2000 thru Vista/Server 2008 R1).